# Why is the following default copying syntax invalid in C++?

Tags: c++, copy, copy-constructor

I wrote a simple C++ program to test out the concept of default copying behavior in C++. So, I have a sample class X and I create an object called "var" of class X and then I try to initialize another object named "defaultCopyObject" with "var" assuming that the default copying behavior is just the memberwise copy of one object to the other. I have understood the concept correctly but I am not able to get my head around the syntax used for initialization.

```
X defaultCopyObject{var};// this code snippet works perfectly fine

// this code snippet returns a compile time error
X defaultCopyObject;
defaultCopyObject{var};
```

Can someone explain me why is the former statement valid and the latter invalid?

Comment: I mean this is a perfectly valid question, I see no reason to downvote it.

Comment: Not really _"perfect"_ by means of a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It's not "valid" at all. You failed to present a testcase, despite the instructions of both the Tour and of the Help Centre.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`X defaultCopyObject{var};` calls a constructor of `X`. A constructor can only be called when a variable is first instantiated.

In the second example, the variable has already been instantiated when calling `defaultCopyObject{var};` and therefore calling the constructor for a second time is not possible.

Note that you can still use the *copy assignment operator* after the variable has been instantiated:

```
defaultCopyObject = var;
```

Comment: yeah I know regarding the assignment operator but I just read about the initialization list construction syntax. Hence tried using it.

Answer (score 3):

The first is an initializer list constructor or a default constructor if the initializer list one doesn't exist. You cannot make a call to a constructor after declaring an object like that, which is what it looks like that code is doing

Comment: So, the constructor in the class looks like the following, X(int i=0):m{i}{}, does the construction of the object defaultCopyObject in the code call this constructor by substituting the value of the member 'm' of object var for 'i'? Or is it something wrong I am assuming.

Answer (score 0):

[Brace initialization syntax](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) like

```
X defaultCopyObject{var};
```

is only valid on declaration of a variable, while using it after isn't possible.

You are in need of an appropriate assignment operator, to move the values to the variable. There are ways (like assigning from [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)), but not using that syntax, that is reserved for declaration.